# ListView default background selector doesn't work

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to solve an issue with default background selector in list view.

I'm using a ListView with a default style. List item contains a few TextViews and an ImageButton. When the image button is not visible (Setting visibility to invisible using the adapter), the background selector works well (There is an on click animation). But, when the ImageButton is visible, there is no onclick animation when clicking on the item (Not the button)..

**List item:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:paddingTop="5dp"
android:paddingBottom="5dp"
android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/time"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="10:20:30"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/type"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Title"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/time"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/openMapButton"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/body"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Long long bodylong bodylong bodylong bodylong bodylong bodylong bodylong body"
    android:layout_below="@+id/type"
    android:layout_alignStart="@id/type"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/openMapButton"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="2"
    />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/openMapButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/open_map"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
```

**ListView:**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".events.EventsHistoryFragment">

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    tools:listitem="@layout/notification_list_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

**Adapter:**

```
    public class EventsAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    public EventsAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, boolean autoRequery) {
        super(context, c, autoRequery);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.notification_list_item, parent, false);

        EventViewHolder viewHolder = new EventViewHolder();
        viewHolder.time = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.time);
        viewHolder.type = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.type);
        viewHolder.body = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.body);
        viewHolder.openMapButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.openMapButton);
        viewHolder.openMapButtonListener = new ShowMapButtonClickListener();
        viewHolder.openMapButton.setOnClickListener(viewHolder.openMapButtonListener);

        view.setTag(viewHolder);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

        EventViewHolder viewHolder = (EventViewHolder) view.getTag();

        long timestamp = cursor.getLong(EventData.TIMESTAMP_COLUMN_ID);
        String type = cursor.getString(EventData.TYPE_COLUMN_ID);
        String body = cursor.getString(EventData.BODY_COLUMN_ID);
        double latitude = cursor.getDouble(EventData.LOCATION_LATITUDE_COLUMN_ID);
        double longitude = cursor.getDouble(EventData.LOCATION_LONGITUDE_COLUMN_ID);
        String humanReadableType = ServiceEvents.getReadableEventName(context, type);

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        Date date = new Date(timestamp);

        viewHolder.time.setText(sdf.format(date));
        viewHolder.type.setText(humanReadableType);
        viewHolder.body.setText(body);
        if(latitude == ServiceEvents.UNKNOWN_COORIDATE) {
            viewHolder.openMapButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            viewHolder.openMapButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            viewHolder.openMapButtonListener.bind(context, latitude, longitude, humanReadableType);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior of the android list items is determined by the selector 
**?android:attr/selectableItemBackground** so your RelativeLayout of your ListItem should be:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:paddingTop="5dp"
android:paddingBottom="5dp"
android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
>
```

Notice the last attribute **android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"**

Comment: It doesn't help. Nothing changed. When the Image button is visible the background doesn't animate